# Count total lines written by a specific user throughout all its projects in Github

Tags: git, github

I'm wondering if there's a way in Github to count the total amount of lines of code a specific user has written throughout *all* of its projects.

`git log --author="<author>" --oneline --shortstat` would list the amount of code for a given repo, but I'm wondering if there is a way to list all the code a user has ever pushed to Github.

Comment: You could use the API, get all repo contributed to, and get the lines written for each repo (which is how I tried to do it) but that seems overcomplicated...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've written a basic program that will do this: http://stats.kaufer.org/

The source of it is on Github here: https://github.com/mjkaufer/stats

Basically, I ended up using Github's API.

Comment: It seems to be down sadly.

Comment: No, it just takes some time to boot, because it's kind of hosted on a public-esque server

Comment: If someone wants to fork this to a non-meteor, purely client side app, that'd be great because meteor is killing its free hosting soon...